# Laravel + Angular 2 http POST error

Tags: php, angular, laravel, post

Im currently building a login system using angular 2 framework (ionic). This login have 2 post data which are:

Email
Password

I've built the API and ran using postman. Everything is fine. It's returning desired response. But the angular 2 POST doesnt seems to do what it should do. For example this is my request code:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({email: email, password: password});

this.http.post('https://dev.domain.com/api/login', data)
.subscribe(
        res => {
            console.log(res);
            loading.dismiss();
        },
        err => {
            console.log("Error occured");
            loading.dismiss();
        }
);
```

Laravel returns 200 response and desired data but Angular 2 is always identifying the response as error. This is my Laravel codes:

```
public function login(Request $request) {

    $data = $request->json()->all();

    $email = $data['email'];
    $password = $data['password'];
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        $user = User::where('email', $email)->first();
        return response()->json(['data' => $user])->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    } else {
        $returnData = array(
            'status' => 'error',
            'message' => 'An error occurred!'
        );
        return response()->json($returnData, 500)->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }
}
```

I tried installing CORS plugin. Still seems to not solve this issue.

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTTP status code From 500 to 200 or leave empty.

```
return response()->json($returnData, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

OR

```
return response()->json($returnData)->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't return a 500 for a failed auth either, at best its a 403. Usually though, you just return it as a 200 as in "the request is a success, nothing failed" but the password is incorrect, so you return the status of error, and handle that in your js